# want to connect to the same database table but with different values

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i have this code where i want to start a new connection to the same database but have different values to be getting unlike in the previous connection to the database, however whenever i start the connection what i receive in my website is an error saying "Couldn't fetch mysqli" please help i dont know what to do

i tried closing the connection to the database by using "mysqli_close($conn);"  but didn't work

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM userissues, response WHERE response.idmatch = userissues.emailcount");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0){
    mysqli_close($conn);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM userissues WHERE departmentSent = '$_SESSION[user_email]' ORDER BY dateSent DESC");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 0){
        echo '<p style="margin-left: 162px; width: 300px; float: left; height: 50px;">you have no emails</p>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>
            <a href="email_preview.php?id=<?php echo $row['emailcount'];?>&site=inbox">
                <?php

            echo '
            <table border="1" id="'.$row["emailcount"].'" style="margin-left: 162px; width: 300px; float: left; height: 50px;">
            <tr><td>'.$row["user_email"].'</td></tr><br>
            <tr><td>'.$row["dateSent"].'</td></tr><br>
            <tr><td>'.$row["subject"].'</td></tr><br>
            <tr><td> '.$row["report"].'</td></tr><br><br>
            </table>
            </a>
            ';

                }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}elseif($count > 0){
        mysqli_close($conn);

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM userissues, response WHERE userissues.departmentSent = '$_SESSION[user_email]' AND response.user_receiver = '$_SESSION[user_email]' ORDER BY userissues.dateSent AND response.dateResponded DESC");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count == 0){
            echo '<p style="margin-left: 162px; width: 300px; float: left; height: 50px;">you have no emails</p>';
        }else{
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo'';
            }
        }
}
```

i just want to establish a new connection to the same database but with different values

Comment: If all you want to do is COUNT the rows in a query then you would be well advised to do a `SELECT COUNT()` rather than a query that will return a resultset that you dont actually want to look at.

Comment: In  which line you have errors?

Comment: i'm not just trying to count them, i was planning on inserting the data from the new result query in the while loop

Comment: on mysqli_close($conn); after elseif @Nasser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the connection `mysqli_close($conn);` you can no longer issue queries using that connection. Basically that will destroy the pipe through which you can issue queries and retrieve results.

I think what you actually want to do is `mysqli_free_result($result)`

> The [documentation for `mysqli_free_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)
>
> Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
> Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

If you really have to close the connection to the database `mysqli_close($conn);` then you will have to issue another `$con = mysqli_connect()` to create another connection. However this is a comparatively slow process, and one script should really only open one connection.

Comment: it did work! there are no more error thank you so much